# Print module and wkhtmltopdf - How to install on linux centos shared hosting

Tags: 7, theming, files

I use The [Print 7.2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module and want to work with The wkhtmltopdf library.

I downloaded library files from this address: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf  ([this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/306882#comment-11336385) adviced to download this version from git )
and extract downloaded folder on **sites/all/libraries**.
I enable the wkhtmltopdf handler module and go to configuration pdf of print module . see these files for choose :

- wkhtmltopdf
  (sites/all/libraries/wkhtmltopdf-master/docs/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)
- wkhtmltopdf
  (sites/all/libraries/wkhtmltopdf-master/src/pdf/wkhtmltopdf.cc)
- wkhtmltopdf (sites/all/libraries/wkhtmltopdf-master/wkhtmltopdf.qrc)
- wkhtmltopdf (sites/all/libraries/wkhtmltopdf-master/wkhtmltopdf.pro)

when select one of these and go to status page recieved this error on status report:

> Unsupported wkhtmltopdf version -
> The currently selected version of
> wkhtmltopdf () is not supported. Please update to a newer version.

I read several article about installation of this library but in those articles use command line . I can't understand how i can install this library and pdf generator on my drupal site.where is my require file library?

My host is linux centos 64bit - 6.x
I use cpanel.
and I am admin of server and have access to ssh.

Please help me. THank you beforehand.

Comment: The github project is the 'source' code. You need to compile it to an executable or download the pre-compiled version.

Comment: thanks @beebee. where can I download the pre-compiled version? please give me link of suitable  version for me (centos)  to download.

Comment: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: @beebee very very thanks for your replies. should I download centos rpm file?  https://bitbucket.org/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/wkhtmltox-0.13.0-alpha-7b36694_linux-centos6-amd64.rpm....?   after download and copy file to sites/all/libraries  how can I install its for my drupal?  I will need to shell and ssh?  how?

Comment: please help me.Should I download rpm file for centos? copy this  to site/all/libraries after download of file? For install rpm file should I run any command? what? thanks

Comment: I don't have CentOS on me to test, I've tried it on my Ubuntu with no luck, Print module can't find wkhtmltopdf... I'll try again later, sorry not very helpful.